# Is there any difference between using useRef().current instead of useRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about the declaration of references in React using the useRef hook.

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
 const inputRef = useRef(null).current;

 ...

 inputRef?.focus();
```

and this:

```
 const inputRef = useRef(null);
 
 ...

 inputRef.current?.focus();
```

??

In my code the behaviour is the same but in some situations, with other use cases, I have different results.

For example:

```
 const arrayRef = useRef(null);
 arrayRef.current = data; // data is an array of numbers
```

seems not to be the same as

```
 const arrayRef = useRef(null).current;
 arrayRef = data;
```

But why? (Not really sure if isn't the same, but my code works unexpectedly using the second method.)

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have `useRef(null).current` because there's no way you can assign anything to the ref (as you've pointed out)? Show more context.

Comment: A ref is an object with a `current` property. That `current` value can change, and so the ref object is a convenient wrapper around that changing value, so you can pass the REFERENCE to the value around your app and not just pass the value. When you use `current` instead of the object, you are unwrapping the ref and so now its just a normal value. If it changes, you might not receive that change everywhere you are using the ref, because you're referring to a value and no longer the original ref. Don't unwrap it, just pass the ref around and use `ref.current` to access the value when you need.

Comment: There is a reason the devs at React decided to do it this way. Don't break it.

Comment: @Raul - nice one! That's a very special case. The ref itself in that component will never be reassigned and the value it holds (the Animated Value) is manipulated via other mechanisms.

Comment: @Adam yeah my fault, just imagine that "null" is "new Animated.Value(0)" for example. 
It was to make a quick example Take a look here https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/adding-animations-to-your-react-native-app-made-easy/

Comment: @Raul - context counts. With the context, it becomes very clear and obvious why the code is written that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with using `.current` is that that'll extract the current reference *immediately*. If the value is extracted at the time of render, but later a re-render occurs, but the initial render still uses the extracted reference somewhere, it'll be a reference to the *old value* in the ref which may not exist yet.

For a quick example:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('custom-focus-the-input', () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <input ref={inputRef} />
  );
};
```

Above, the ref *must* be used as a plain ref. You can't extract it into its `current` value until you're inside the event listener, because the ref's reference changes on first render.

Also, for a ref to get its `.current` assigned properly, you have to put the ref itself in the returned JSX - don't put the `.current` value into the JSX, because that won't result in the `.current` property of the ref changing.

---

In general - only extract the `.current` value from the ref until you need to use it shortly in subsequent *synchronous* code.

Answer (score 1):

`useRef` (like almost all react hooks) effectively supplies an instance variable to something that doesn't have an instance (a functional component isn't backed by an instance - it's a function, but react keeps track of it's lifecycle via fiber's and other cool magic).

Now that you know it's just an instance variable, it becomes clear that instance variables are only useful if they can be assigned things.

[In the context you've given](https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/adding-animations-to-your-react-native-app-made-easy/):

```js
const animatedOpacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

The instance variable is assigned an `Animated.Value`. It never needs to be reassigned because `Animated.Value` (which is the `current` property of the ref) is manipulated/reassigned using other functions, like `Animated.timing`.